# how to get response from directions API google maps?

Tags: ios, google-maps, directions

I am trying to get the response Google Directions API. Can you please find the error in this?

```
NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@origin=%f,%f&destination=%f,%f&key=%@",@"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?",
                     self.marker.position.latitude,
                     self.marker.position.longitude,
                     self.SecondMarker.position.latitude,
                     self.SecondMarker.position.longitude,
                     @"AIzaSyDhZvxehd6ZDKFOB67WIyeLpy7KITwRPw0"];
    //str = [str stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    str = [str stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLFragmentAllowedCharacterSet]];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:str];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    //NSString *params = @"";
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    //[request setHTTPBody:[params dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
    [[session dataTaskWithRequest:request
                completionHandler:^(NSData *data,
                                    NSURLResponse *response,
                                    NSError *error) {
                    // handle response
                    if (!error && [data length]) {
                        NSLog(@"Reponse: %@",response);
                    }
                    else{
                        NSLog(@"%@",error.description);
                    }
                }] resume];
```

Please suggest some lines of code?

Error Message :

> ```
> Reponse: <NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x60800002d480> { URL: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=-33.860000,151.200000&destination=-34.224142,150.068408&key=AIzaSyDhZvxehd6ZDKFOB67WIyeLpy7KITwRPw0
> ```
>
> } { status code: 200, headers {
>           "Cache-Control" = "public, max-age=86400";
>           "Content-Encoding" = gzip;
>           "Content-Length" = 23856;
>           "Content-Type" = "application/json; charset=UTF-8";
>           Date = "Tue, 25 Apr 2017 08:48:36 GMT";
>           Expires = "Wed, 26 Apr 2017 08:48:36 GMT";
>           Server = mafe;
>           Vary = "Accept-Language";
>           "alt-svc" = "quic=\":443\"; ma=2592000; v=\"37,36,35\"";
>           "x-frame-options" = SAMEORIGIN;
>           "x-xss-protection" = "1; mode=block";
>       } }

Comment: add your error message .

Comment: check the edit please

Comment: @HarjotSinghPanesar You are not getting the error instead of you are getting response successfully now you need to access data and serialized JSON from it

Comment: This doesn't seem to be an error. You are just printing the `NSURLResponse` (which has a HTTP Code of 200 meaning OK), instead of `data` in the completion block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this

```
   NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@origin=%f,%f&destination=%f,%f&key=%@",@"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?",
                     self.marker.position.latitude,
                     self.marker.position.longitude,
                     self.SecondMarker.position.latitude,
                     self.SecondMarker.position.longitude,
                     @"AIzaSyDhZvxehd6ZDKFOB67WIyeLpy7KITwRPw0"];

str = [str stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLFragmentAllowedCharacterSet]];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:str];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

[request addValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request addValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:configuration delegate:nil delegateQueue:nil];
[[session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data,NSURLResponse *response,NSError *error) {

                if (!error && [data length])
                {
                    NSLog(@"Reponse: %@",response);

                    NSError *e = nil;
                    NSDictionary *JSONarray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: data options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&e];
                    NSLog(@"Response dictionary is%@",JSONarray);
                }
                else
                {
                    NSLog(@"%@",error.description);
                }
            }] resume];
```